# How can i use Longclick method in android

Tags: android

we are making an off line dictionary  . So for this purpose, we are using long click() method. After selecting a word in a text file using long click() we want a button  for meaning will pop up.So how we can do this? we want a button from where we'll refer to our dictionary.
our code of long click is-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                   "kutu",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("", "Longpress detected");
        }

    });
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use onlongclick listener for this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
         public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
             return true;
         }
     });
```